# Jupyter shows no output

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am running few cells on my Jupyter notebook. It looks like after running the cell I don't get output second time. I have to restart the kernel, after which I am able to see the output on running the cell. But then when I try and rerun the cell there is no output again. Not sure the reason. I am using jupyter with anaconda.

I read some thread which said the output going to Ipython terminal in their case, I am not sure similar thing is happening in my case or is it something else.

I know Question is little vague but then I can not think of what more Info I can provide

Thanks

Comment: Good morning. If the output is not coming is it showing some error message or is it just blank. Can you also tell which OS you are using?

Comment: It is not showing the output. I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago) 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11027